# eclipselink stored procedure array

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I want to execute stored procedure (oracle) with input - array of number from eclipselink.

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
StoredProcedureCall call = new StoredProcedureCall();
call.setProcedureName("P_TEST2");
ReadQuery mquery = new DataReadQuery();

call.addNamedArgument("x");
call.addNamedOutputArgument("z");

mquery.setCall(call);

int [] x = {1,2,3};
Query query = ((JpaEntityManager)entityManager.getDelegate()).createQuery(mquery)
    .setParameter("x", x);
DatabaseRecord record = (DatabaseRecord) query.getSingleResult();
System.out.println(record.get("z"));
```

Procedure itself

```
create or replace procedure p_test2(
  x in numeric_array,
  z out numeric
)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN x.first .. x.last
      LOOP
        INSERT INTO TEST2(ID,VALUE) VALUES (SEQ1.nextval,i);
      END LOOP;
  commit;
  z := seq1.currval;
END;
/
```

But there is problem with it, problem in arrays, I think.

Need your help.

Answer (score -2):

Solved it in that way:

1. writing function/procedure, that accepts string (array separated by space or comma)
2. in function parse parameters and convert them to table of numeric (or any needed type)
3. calling needed function
4. return needed result